# Angular2 - changing model data using Promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am experimenting with Angular2 (with no experience of Angular1), I have used data binding successfully, but I now want to add promises into the mix to simulate an async request for data.
In the following code, setting newData to an object literal works fine, but setting it to an existing populated object does not work.

After trying this for over a day, I need some help.
I'm looking for the simplest way to have my promise return some data and have it update the interpolated value in the template. I've read that zones are sometimes used for this, but at the moment, want to keep this to the bare minimum, to help my understanding (hence I've removed factory classes, interfaces, and dependency injection from the sample code)

I suspect the answer is in [this victorsavkin post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/110170125256/change-detection-in-angular-2), but at my current level of understanding, it's beyond me.

http://plnkr.co/edit/amLIZWe5UI9jlvpVGv9V?p=preview

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {MockData} from './mock-data.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template:`
    <h1>
    Hello {{data.name}}
    </h1>`,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  public data = {}

  constructor() {
    new Promise((response, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        newData = {name:'Sid'}      //works
        //newData = MockData        //doesn't work
        response(newData)  
      }, 1000)

    })
    .then(response => this.data = response)
  }

}
```

mock-data.js

```
exports MockData = {
  name:'Nancy'
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with the Promise, but with the import. If you remove everything from the constructor and add just `console.log(MockData)` it produces the same error...

Comment: You spotted my incorrect path typo, which I should have spotted from the console output, but wasn't wasn't the problem I was looking to fix. Even moving MockData directly into app.js failed.

Comment: Also having a problem getting it to work in IE11, but that is another issue: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/issues/41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made these two changes to your plunker to get it to work:

```
export var MockData = {
  name:'Brian'
}

import {MockData} from '../mock-data.ts'
```

New [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLXXYd4rDtia2LlB6lD5?p=preview).

You also don't have to initialize the `data` property if you use the [Elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators) (?.):

```
Hello {{data?.name}}
```

Then in your component just:

```
public data;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So ignoring my 2 idiotic mistakes (imports instead of import, and an incorrect path), why does 'export var' work, whereas just 'export' or 'export public' not work?

Comment: The elvis operator info was very useful @mark-rajcok. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators  explains why the whole view crashes (because MockData is null), so the real problem lies with my lack of understanding of TypeScript variable /object declarations, or variable scope